# Combine Magento TAF with EcomDev_PHPUnit fixtures

Tags: database, ecomdev-phpunit, testing, taf

I want to use the [Magento Test Automation Framework](https://github.com/magento/taf) to create a Smoke Test Suite, i.e. a test suite that quickly tests a cross section of the store to check for serious errors, *not* to test the correct behaviour of all features.

The included test suite does not serve this purpose well, it tests the shop very thoroughly and creates test data for each test by foot in the backend (which takes way too much time).

Writing custom tests for my test suite is not a problem, but I also would like to optimize the creation of test data.

My tests will run on the same machine as the SUT, so it seems natural to create a test fixture directly in the database instead of using Selenium. **Now my question is:** Is there a clean way to integrate the fixture system of [EcomDev_PHPUnit](https://github.com/EcomDev/EcomDev_PHPUnit) into TAF?

The problem is that the fixture is coupled to `EcomDev_PHPUnit_Test_Case` and the TAF tests have to extend `Mage_Selenium_TestCase`. I would like to use `EcomDev_PHPUnit_Model_Fixture` as a standalone component, is that possible? Or are there better ways to create database fixtures for a TAF test suite?

Comment: I think fixtures should use magento models (like in magento 2) rather than inserting data to the table like in EcomDev. See https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/master/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Mage/Core/_files/store.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fixture magic happens in the listener method `\EcomDev_PHPUnit_Test_Listener::startTest()`:

```
public function startTest(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test)
    // [...]
    EcomDev_PHPUnit_Test_Case_Util::getFixture(get_class($test))
        ->setScope(EcomDev_PHPUnit_Model_Fixture_Interface::SCOPE_LOCAL)
        ->loadByTestCase($test);
    $annotations = $test->getAnnotations();
    EcomDev_PHPUnit_Test_Case_Util::getFixture()
        ->setOptions($annotations['method'])
        ->apply();
```

So you could pretty much execute this code (passing your test class) manually before each test. It already read the `@loadFixture` annotation of your test method.

To have everything working automatically as you are used to from `EcomDev_PHPUnit` you need to the necessary files from `EcomDev_PHPUnit` installed (installing the full package should be fine) and you have to add the entry

```
<listeners>
    <listener file="app/code/community/EcomDev/PHPUnit/Test/Listener.php" class="EcomDev_PHPUnit_Test_Listener" />    
</listeners>
```

In your `phpunit.xml`. This should not conflict with TAF in any way, as it is not necessary at any point to extent from `EcomDev_PHPUnit_Test_Case`. Especially note, that the above listener requires an instance of `PHPUnit_Framework_Test` only.

PS: I am referring to the [latest version on GitHub of EcomDev_PHPUnit](https://github.com/IvanChepurnyi/EcomDev_PHPUnit/commit/9b85f00e92f7c03632cf13a156d4c191ecd961ab) as there were some changes in structure recently.

Comment: Thanks, this put me in the right direction! Additionally, `Mage/App.php` had to be included in the `bootstrap.php` and the `same-db` flag of EcomDev_PHPUnit set to `1` so that the fixture can operate on the "live" database. There are still some issues that I have to figure out but I managed to combine the fixture system with TAF with your help, so I'll accept the answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You should think about MageBehat for this purpose:

https://github.com/magento-hackathon/MageBehat

Behat is based on Selenium and there are a few testcases already implemented, like checkout.

Comment: It's a promising project but it does not solve the fixture problem (yet), or am I missing something?

Comment: No, you are right. I think it were better a comment :)